# Issue with my Python environment

Tags: python

Brand new to Python, coming from Ruby.

I have a script that *works perfectly* if I run it form `ipython` or `ipython qtconsole`.  I then tried to turn it into an executable script -- threw `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top.

Running the script throws an error:

`$ ./script/myscript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script/myscript.py", line 6, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml`

Obviously there's something wrong with how python is loading modules (as it works perfectly fine from the REPL) but I have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is likely happening is you have more than one version of Python installed on your system, and the `yaml` module is only installed in one of them. When you run `ipython` it's using one version, but your script's shebang line is finding another version. Run

```
head `which ipython`
```

and see if it matches up to the result of `which python` (I'm betting it won't). Once you know the path to the python binary being used by `ipython`, you can specifically define it in your script's shebang line.

As a long-term fix, edit your `$PATH` variable and put the directory containing your desired version of Python ahead of the directory shown by `which python`, so that you can continue to use `#!/usr/bin/env python` as a shebang.

Comment: You bet they dont match.  Thanks for that. Do most people `brew install python` or use the system version?

Comment: @Brandon - I actually use MacPorts, as they have many more add-on modules available as packages, and overall the quality control seems to be better than homebrew. The system Python is generally to be avoided except for system tasks, as it doesn't include all the components needed to build some modules, for example. I've seen a lot more questions here on SO related to `brew` issues than `port` ones, if that's any measure. However, some people really prefer `brew`. YMMV :)

Answer (score 1):

ipython must be pointing at a different version of python than what is in PYTHONPATH.

You can find out by looking at cat /usr/local/bin/ipython.

Look at

[ipython reads wrong python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386048/ipython-reads-wrong-python-version)