# IPython sys.path different from python sys.path

Tags: python, import, path, ipython, sys

I generally use IPython and only recently noticed that the the search path for imports is wrong in the regular python shell. From what I understand, sys.path inherits from PYTHONPATH (although I don't know where PYTHONPATH lives), is this different in IPython? I'm worried that this effecting installations. For instance I just tried

```
pip install --upgrade gensim
```

which failed because it couldn't resolve the scipy dependency, which I already have installed.
So I dove a little bit deeper and found in Ipython

```
import gensim
gensim.__version__
```

returns .9.1
while in python

```
import gensim
gensim.__version__
```

returns .8.9

Here is what the Ipython version of sys.path looks like:

```
['',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/bin',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybing-0.12-py2.7.egg',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python27.zip',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygoogle',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
    '/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

and the regular python script sys.path:

```
['',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybing-0.12-py2.7.egg',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python27.zip',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygoogle',
'/Users/change/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

Comment: For more about how sys.path works, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38403654/850326

Answer (score 3):

Probably too late for you now, but the answer here may help you too: [ipython reads wrong python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386048/ipython-reads-wrong-python-version) . Basically the ipython script can directly reference a specific python binary rather than the one that you'd get if you just ran python directly.

Comment: The first comment under the question of your link helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a brew installed version of Python on my mac. For some reason that couldn't use the system libraries. After `brew uninstall python` it worked again, because the default python was switched back to /usr/bin/python.

Also playing around with `which python`, `which ipython` and opening up /usr/bin/python, /usr/local/bin/python, /usr/bin/ipython and /usr/local/bin/ipython and doing the imports there might help you find out where it is exactly going wrong.

Comment: Mac has wierd issues when setting `sys.path` and `sys.executable` on macs, because it has to guess at where the actual python executable is; DARWIN doesn't pass the whole path of python to itself. :(

Answer (score 0):

You may have your virtual environment activated which is ignoring the system path.

It can be fixed by running this in terminal (After closing notebook etc):

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages ~
```