# ipython notebook & script difference - loading DLLs

Tags: python, .net, ipython, jupyter, python.net

Did anyone notice the difference in loading .NET dlls between IPython/Jupyter notebook/(qt)console and normal python scripts using pythonnet?

Is this a bug/behavior caused on pythonnet or ipython side?

This works in ipython and python interactive console:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"C:\path2dll\dotnetdll")
```

But in regular python scripts, the sys.path has to be appended with the path to DLL:

```
import clr
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\path2dll")
clr.AddReference("dotnetdll")
```

Possibly similar problem:

[Permission denied on dl.open() with ipython but not with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097551/oserror-with-only-ipython-and-not-with-python/32493224#32493224)

Comment: Hmh, what is your question here?

Comment: Is this a bug/behavior caused on pythonnet or ipython side?

Comment: i want consistent behavior on both sides, something is definitely different in the notebook mode

Answer (score 1):

in interactive mode python interpreter appends empty string `""` to `sys.path`. As a side effect of this the buggy AssemblyManager in pythonnet was loading assemblies from full path only in interpreter mode.