# IPython prioritizes the stdlib over the current directory in sys.path

Tags: ipython, sys.path

In an interactive python shell, `''` is the first entry in `sys.path`, but in IPython, the interpreters stdlib paths come first:

Python:

```
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jul 22 2022, 17:09:35) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys; sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

IPython:

```
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jul 22 2022, 17:09:35) [GCC 9.4.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import sys; sys.path
Out[1]: 
['/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

I get this on several systems and also on https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/, so it's not a local configuration issue. This did not use to be the case, see also the paths in [IPython sys.path different from python sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209192/ipython-sys-path-different-from-python-sys-path) (old question with a different problem).

Is this supposed to happen, and how can I disable it and have the same path as Python (without manually editing `sys.path` in every session)?