# Is it possible to use ipython based on a builtin python

Tags: python, ipython, built-in, paraview

I am using paraview 4.3.1 in Centos 7. There is a built-in python named **pvpython**:

```html
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jan 15 2015, 09:36:49)
[GCC 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys;sys.path
['', '/tmp/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3/site-packages/vtk', '/tmp/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3/site-packages', '/tmp/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3', '/tmp/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3/lib/python27.zip', '/tmp/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3/lib/python2.7', '/tmp/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/tmp/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/tmp/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/tmp/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/tmp/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

The problem is, original pvpython do not support many useful features such as code completion. And there is no setup_tools in the pvpython, so I cannot install new modules to the built-in python.

Could anyone help me to install ipython on this built-in python?

Comment: Install pip see instructions here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html
It will install setuptools if needed and then you can `pip install ipython`

Comment: I just tried this tactic:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386048/ipython-reads-wrong-python-version) 
But it failed, it seems that I cannot pass arguments to pvpython.

Answer (score 2):

See the install instructions for get-pip:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

However, you must use the `pvpython` instead of `python` when using the install instructions.

Depending on how you install it, you may end up with more than one easy_install or pip on your path. Just make sure you're using the one associated with `pvpython` - look at the script you're running to find out (it's just a shell script).

Once you've done that, installing ipython should be the same as installing it with any other version of python (assuming that `pvpython` doesn't break anything that ipython needs).

Comment: AFAIK, this is not the preferred way to do that anymore. You can use `getpip.py` to bootstrap both `setuptools` and `pip` in one go. See the link provided by @achampion

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @cel.  Changed answer to use get-pip instead of ez_install.

Comment: I tried get-pip.py like this:
'
>>> execfile("get-pip.py")
'
But I get an error
'No module named 'pip._vendor.requests''