# How do I change the kernel/python version for iPython?

Tags: python, macos, ipython

I have installed iPython using pip in OS X 10.10, and it gave me the "ipython" and "ipython2" commands, which run great, but which use OS X's default python version 2.7.9. I downloaded and installed the latest release of Python3.4 and can load it with the command "python3," but cannot find a way to get iPython to use this version of python. The iPython Web site states the package can be used with python versions 3.3 and above, but I cannot find any instruction on how to change the default python version used.

So far I have found that the jupyter package for iPython has a kernel specification in /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/, which is just a folder called "python2" containing a json file that points to the system's python 2.7.6, but altering this to point to the new python3.4 installation does not work. My guess is this configuration is for the ipython notebook.

I've also tried the approach here: [ipython reads wrong python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386048/ipython-reads-wrong-python-version)

In doing so I've duplicated the ipython2 command in /user/local/bin/ and edited it to use the python3 interpreter located at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3, however, this gives me an error "ImportError: No module named 'IPython'," which suggests the python3 installation does not have ipython installed.

To tackle this, I've tried uninstalling ipython and reinstalling it using pip, but it just targets the system's Python 2.7 installation and does nothing for python3.

Does anyone know how to configure iPython to use a different python version, or even install a separate ipython installation for python3? Ultimately it would be nice to quickly switch back and forth depending on my needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found the answer. In essence, this stems from not understanding the python installation layout and how resources are separated between installed interpreters. It appears each python version will have its own repository of tools, and the current "pip" command I had installed on the system was mapped for use with python 2.7, so all libraries, tools, and other details it managed where available only to python 2.7. This included iPython.

I thought that installing python3 would make all these libraries available to the new interpreter by default, but it appears the system keeps them all separate (which makes sense). The main issue here was continuing to use "pip" which targeted the old installation, instead of the new "pip3" command included with python3. By using pip3 to reinstall iPython, I was able to get iPython3 installed properly.

Unfortunately this setup means needing to re-download other libraries, but that's not too difficult.

It might seem like a trivial issue in hindsight, but this had me completely stuck. I hope this helps someone else in this situation.