# pip install for mpld3

Tags: python, pip

I just did a

```
 sudo pip install matplotlib
```

which worked fine. Then

```
 sudo pip install matplotlib
```

Details:

```
$sudo pip install mpld3
Downloading/unpacking mpld3
  Downloading mpld3-0.2.tar.gz (1.1MB): 1.1MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/mpld3/setup.py) egg_info for package mpld3

Installing collected packages: mpld3
  Running setup.py install for mpld3

Successfully installed mpld3
Cleaning up...
```

So mpld3 also installed fine.

For some reason matplotlib is showing up in python, but not mpld3:

```
In [3]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [4]: plt.plot([3,1,4,1,5], 'ks-', mec='w', mew=5, ms=20)
Out[4]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x103ab4d10>]

In [5]: plt.show()
```

works fine ..

But:

```
In [6]: import mpld3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-25a6968c2f16> in <module>()
----> 1 import mpld3

ImportError: No module named mpld3
```

Is it necessary to update e.g. PYTHONPATH or some other env var?

**UPDATE** Answering (good) question from @infinity about the pip vs ipython versions:

```
$which pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/bin/pip
18:20:42/lightbox2 $which ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
18:20:45/lightbox2 $which python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/bin/python
18:23:58/lightbox2 $sudo pip install ipython
Password:
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Type: `which pip`, and `which ipython`. Show us the answer :)

Comment: @Infinity  I see where you are going here: the ipython is from /usr/local/bin yet the python is from brew.  So then, i need to figure out how to connect up the ipython with the brew python.

Comment: @Infinity  Pls see updated OP

Comment: Using the ipython, can you please write "import sys; sys.executable"?

Comment: @Infinity  yes it is the incorrect one (/usr/bin/python) . The only suggestion I see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386048/ipython-reads-wrong-python-version requires to update the ipython script. That is ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ipython executable is hardcoded to /usr/bin/python. The best workaround I can see is to change the first line from

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

That fixed the issue for my case of a non-standard python location.

Comment: This is most likely a bad idea, for the reasons explained in a comment on Infinity's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your `where` results, I think your ipython seems to look at the wrong path when trying to import modules.

The complete diagnose and fix (for you and future Googlers):

1. Use `which` (Linux) or `where` (windows) on your command prompt to check the `pip` and `python`/`ipython` paths.

   1.1. If the ipython seems to run from a different path, start it and check where the matching Python installation using `import sys; sys.executable`.
2. Anyway, fix this problem by carefully modifying the PATH environment variable in a way that it will show the path to right Python executable.

Edit: After a bit of extra discussion with the OP (look @ comments), if the ipython installation isn't linked with the python executable, you should change the first line of your ipython file to shabang, then the path of your Python executable. It should look like: `#!/usr/bin/python` when `/usr/bin/python` is the path to the right Python executable.

Edit 2: Better solution for unlinked ipython would be to install ipython for the right Python version, using `python -m pip install ipython` (thanks @abarnert and @koffein).

Comment: The "path to right python executable" is not sufficient here.  The PATH does point to the correct one.  The issue appears to be there is no way to configure ipython to point to a different version of python - short of modifying the ipython script itself.

Comment: Maybe editing the first line /usr/local/bin/ipython to `#!/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/bin/python` will do?

Comment: That is what I have been saying is required. But that is ugly. It is surprising there were no means to configure ipython to point to a different python short of mangling the ipython script itself.  In my own version I have changed to !/usr/bin/env python

Comment: Have you trying to install ipython using pip? (`pip install ipython`). You pip runs from the right path, I think it should work

Comment: The OP shows that I had re-done *pip install ipython*.  That is a reasonable suggestion. I am just going to live with the update to the ipython script that I mentioned.

Comment: I am going to make an answer that says to change the ipython script to #!/usr/bin/env python.   But you have been helpful so will upvote you.

Comment: Also editing my own answer to include this line, if you don't mind.

Comment: The `ipython` executable is just a very thin script that wraps up the actual `ipython` module, which is installed in the site-packages of one Python or another. If you just point it at a different Python, with a different version of IPython, or no IPython at all, it will break. Don't do that. Instead, either only install IPython for the one Python version you care about, or install a separate IPython script for each Python (which may require renaming the script after it's installed, or having separate `bin` directories and symlinking from there).

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you start the python console from the terminal with `ipython`. If you want to ensure that you are installing the packages to the right python installation, use

```
sudo ipython -m pip install mpld3
```

So automatically the right pip (and the right paths) should be used.

Comment: That is interesting. However, the root issue is actually that ipython is pointing to the incorrect python installation.

Comment: I actually like that solution. Nice one. +1

Answer (score 0):

The `ipython` script is just a very thin wrapper around the actual IPython module, installed into Python's site-packages.

Just changing its `#!` line to point at a different Python is almost always a bad idea. That other Python may have a different IPython version in its site-packages/dist-packages, or may not have one at all.

---

Of course if you only want one `ipython`, it's just a matter of installing it with the right version of Python, and *not* installing it for any other Python.

The problem most people run into is that they accidentally install it for two different Pythons, and whichever one they installed second (or, occasionally, whichever one ends up in a winning location on the PATH) ends up being the one they use, even though it's not the one they intended.

If you don't want IPython for that second Python version, just don't install it. Or, if you already did, uninstall it for both Python versions, then reinstall it for just the one you want.

---

What if you want IPython for multiple Python versions?

Unfortunately, they're all going to try to install with the same name, `ipython`. Maybe `ipython2` and `ipython3`, but that only helps if your own two Python installations are one 2.x and one 3.x. If you have CPython 3.4 and PyPy 3.2, or a system-installed CPython 2.7 and a third-party CPython 2.7, that doesn't do you any good.

So, what can you do?

What I do is to make sure each Python (besides the system-installed one) is configured to use a `scripts`/`bin` directory that isn't on my PATH, then symlink things manually.

So, on both my Mac and Linux systems, `ipython` and `ipython2` both point at the system Python 2.7, and were installed just by `sudo pip install ipython`. But `ipython3` is a symlink that I manually created to where my main Python 3 installation installs binaries. And `ipypy` and `ipypy3` are symlinks to where my main PyPy 2.x and 3.x installations install binaries. (And these of course all parallel symlinks I created named `python`, `python2`, `python3`, `pypy`, and `pypy3`.)

I did have to create these symlinks manually, but that's better than modifying the scripts.