# Have IPython run using Python 3 and not Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed, but when I run IPython using `ipython` from terminal it launches Python 2.  How do I get IPython to run Python 3 instead?  Within the IPython reference it says you just need to use the command `ipython3` from the terminal but this doesn't work.  This question seems to be asked elsewhere on Stackoverflow but I don't see a very clear answer.

Comment: Did you install ipython3? `pip3 install ipython`?

Comment: If you had Python2 when you first installed `ipython` it will run using Python2 even if you install Python3 later. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386048/ipython-reads-wrong-python-version) will help.

Comment: Change system python environment path.

Comment: @SDilmac, why would you suggest doing that?

Comment: @Pushkin Can I simply reinstall `ipython` then just as though I were installing it for the first time?

Comment: @dsaxton, `pip3 install ipython` then simply use `ipython` or `ipython3`, there is no need to do anything else

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Great!  It now runs Python 3 with the command `ipython3`.  If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it.  This actually fixed another problem I was getting ready to ask about.

Comment: All app reading system parameters for working. If you got an default path py27. You need change it. @dstaxton system is py27 reinstall but still not working(if not ask user which python you want ?).

Comment: @dsaxton, sure I added an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install ipython for python3 which you can do with pip:

```
pip3 install ipython
```

Then to start an `ipython2` shell just type `ipython2`, for `ipython3` use `ipython3`

Comment: Typing `ipython` will actually get you whichever version you installed it on most recently.

Comment: In OSX I can't use ipython3 to start py3 version, how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling then reinstalling all my ipython's worked for me:

Uninstall:

```
brew uninstall ipython ## had a version installed w/ brew on my machine
pip2 uninstall ipython
pip3 uninstall ipython
```

Reinstall with pip2 and pip3:

```
pip2 install ipython 
pip3 install ipython
```

Now i get that `ipython2` begins version 2.7 and `ipython` begins version 3.6:

```
mustache:~ r8t$ ipython
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 25 2018, 14:26:36)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: exit()
mustache:~ r8t$ ipython2
Python 2.7.15 (default, May  1 2018, 16:44:37)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.7.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```