# Within IPython how to get the path of the Python driver

Tags: python, ipython

When I am running a script get the path of Python kernel (not mater if it is Python, IPython, or IPython Notebook with non-standard kernel, where I can switch between Py2 and Py3).

When writting (in IPython)

```
import sys
sys.argv
```

I get the path to IPython: `['/usr/local/bin/ipython']`.

Is it possible to get the path to Python as well?

I need it so to match versions of Python from IPython (Notebook) to Spark worker (`PYSPARK_PYTHON`).

Comment: The path to `Python`? What do you mean with Python here

Comment: E.g. a link `python` or `python2` a full path (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/python2`).

Comment: This answer might point you in the right direction:

[ipython reads wrong python version][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386048/ipython-reads-wrong-python-version

Comment: @Maarten Not a bit. IPython Notebook can launch different kernels.

Comment: And you want the path to the python excecutable that your current kernel is running?

Comment: For me sys. argv will indeed give me the ipyhon executable and, running from the note book, sys.path will give me the system python executable. This is on a windows machine

Comment: @Maarten Well, `sys.path` gives access to system paths - they are irrelevant to which Python is in use when executing a particular script. And `sys.argv` for IPython Notebook gives the default kernel, not - one is currently running.

Answer (score 4):

A general way to do so (i.e. working both in scripts, ipython shell and IPython Notebook) is:

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

([Thx Carreau](https://github.com/minrk/findspark/issues/6#issuecomment-132625554)!)