# Why can't I import OpenCV (cv2) in IPython notebook?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Whenever I run

`import cv2`

in an IPython notebook cell, I get an error screen with the message

```
 Kernel Restarting
 The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

Then another dialog stating python quit unexpectedly. Does this mean I cannot run OpenCV in IPython? I cannot seem to find the solution to this anywhere by googling.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Platform: Mac OSX:10.9, IPython 4.0.3, Python 2.7.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slight variant of the solution to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386048/ipython-reads-wrong-python-version.) solved my problem.

The actual python shell that was used by my terminal and many other applications that used OpenCV's cv2 properly was obtained by

```
which python
```

in the Terminal. It returned `/opt/local/bin/python`

The executable for IPython was located in `/usr/local/bin/ipython` -- Open it (it may require superuser privileges)

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/ipython
```

You'd find that the first line of the file is `#!/usr/bin/python` which causes `ipython` to execute the default compiler. This had to be replaced with the line `#!/opt/local/bin/python`.

Then the problem was fixed. I started the IPython notebook as usual and executed `import cv2` and it went well without a glitch!