# CV2 import error with iPython Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, python-import, jupyter-notebook

CV2  can be imported using : terminal-python-import cv2, but

cannot be imported into JupiterNotebook...

[image]

[image]

Reference: 
[Why can't I import OpenCV (cv2) in IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998652/why-cant-i-import-opencv-cv2-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: read this http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

Comment: already tried many time.. Did not work,but thanks anyway.

Comment: Where is `cv2` located? You can find it by importing it and then `print(cv2)`.