# Anaconda + Spark - changing python version for ipython notebooks

Tags: python, apache-spark, anaconda

I installed Anaconda, and try to work with spark on top. 
When I launch spark with Ipython_OPTS="notebook", the python version is the one associated with anaconda's version of python for the notebook.

```
$ conda search python
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
ipython                      0.13                     py26_0  defaults
                          *  4.1.2                    py35_1  defaults
ipython-notebook             0.13.2                   py27_0  defaults
                             4.0.4                    py27_0  defaults
                             4.0.4                    py34_0  defaults
                             4.0.4                    py35_0  defaults
python                       1.0.1                         0  defaults
                          .  2.7.11                        0  defaults
                          *  3.5.1                         0  defaults
```

And if start spark-shell I can precise the environment version on which I am interested (I want 2.7.11) :

```
$ PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Applications/anaconda/anaconda/envs/vingt-sept/bin/python  pyspark
Python 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58)
```

but if I start spark with the ipython notebook then it defaults back to the python 3.5 version :-(

How can I link the default ipython version to the same version as the one of my env "vingt-sept" ?

Comment: this explains how to change python version for ipython http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386048/ipython-reads-wrong-python-version

Answer (score 0):

Similar to how you are setting the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variable for the `pyspark` shell, you can also set this environment variable in your IPython/Jupyter notebook using:

```
import os
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = "/Applications/anaconda/anaconda/envs/vingt-sept/bin/python"
```

Refer to [this blog post](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/using-anaconda-pyspark-distributed-language-processing-hadoop-cluster) for more information about setting `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and other Spark-related environment variables from your notebook.