# error to show graphs and Linear code using SageMath

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, sage

I want to show graph with this code in SageMath 7.3 using jupyter ipython notebook

```
graph_dict = {0: [1,4,5], 1: [2,6], 2: [3,7], 3: [4,2], 4: [0,1], 5: [7, 6], 6: [2], 7: [2]}
G = Graph(graph_dict)
G.show(graph_border=True)
```

the error is

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/tubagus/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyUnicodeUCS2_AsASCIIString
  Referenced from: /Users/tubagus/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/tubagus/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
```

When i use LinearCode() this error occured again

Comment: Could you please share the details on how did you install the libraries and what versions are those? Also what does the following code print into your console? `import sys; print sys.maxunicode`

Comment: I using `conda install numpy in my terminal` and already upgrade in numpy in terminal with newest version, the error still apper. 
in my sagemath the code print `111411`

Comment: Your issue looks similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496685/issue-when-importing-matplotlib. Reinstalling python with proper unicode support should fix the problem

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i already solve the problem after delete my canopy and reinstall sage